# How to count empty range on csv files in one folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have 7 CSV files in one folder two of them are empty on [2..-1] range, how do I count them and get answer 2?

Comment: Simply count the number of files whose size is 0.

Comment: I need to check if a given range in csv files are empty

Comment: Dear OP, please make sure that your question clearly represents what you really want to ask. You asked: _I have 7 CSV files in one folder two of them are empty on [2..-1] range, how do I count them and get answer 2?_ and my comment clearly and precisely answers your question.

Comment: My bad. I fixed my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what empty on [2..-1] range means. Could you please show a CSV example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code iterates over the csv files in current folder, opens them, and checks that every cell in the 3rd, 4th, 5th... columns are empty in every line.

```
separator = ";"

empty_count = Dir["*.csv"].count do |csv|
  File.readlines(csv).all? do |line|
    line.split(separator,-1).drop(2).all? do |cell|
      cell.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the size of the file, there are many methods available. Use something like

```
 File.zero?("csv1.csv")
```

This will give true for the empty csv files.

Comment: If you have spaces in the file, this will return `false`.